# flask-smorest response and return type different

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, marshmallow, flask-smorest

I am learning/working on a Rest Api suing flask-smorest  and adding the schema using marshmallow.

Below is the code that I am confused with and have a question.

```
Schemas.py

class ChildAddressDetailsSchema(Schema):
    class Meta:
        unknown = EXCLUDE

    address_id = fields.String(required=True)
    address_type = fields.String(required=True)
    is_primary = fields.Boolean(required=True)


class ChildAddressDetailsSchemaList(Schema):
    class Meta:
        unknown = EXCLUDE

    person_list = fields.List(fields.Nested(ChildAddressDetailsSchema))
```

Endpoint Implementation

```
@address_blueprint.response(status_code=200, schema=ChildAddressDetailsSchema)
@address_blueprint.get('/child/address/<string:person_id>/list')
def get_child_address(person_id):
    person_address_list = PersonAddressModel.query.filter_by(person_id=person_id).all()
    person_address_dict = [{'address_id': person_address.address_id,
                            'address_type': person_address.address_type,
                            'is_primary': person_address.is_primary} for person_address in person_address_list]

    return person_address_dict
```

The part where I have doubt is even though the schema defined in response of blueprint is
ChildAddressDetailsSchema which is not a list , still I get a valid response.Below is the screenshot of the Insomnia from where I am testing the api.

[image]

I was expecting an empty response or a error since the return of the get function get_child_address is a list of dictionary which is not as per the schema. Could someone please help me figuring out on to how to fix the issue and return type is strictly informed. Is this something that needs to be coded or does marshmallow handles this.

Comment: You need to post a [mre]. You probably have misinterpreted the result. My test code responds ```{}```.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Sorry I missing adding the screenshot of the Insomnia. Added what I am seeing

Comment: Your current code is not a [mre], because it cannot be run standalone. For example, it depends on the ```PersonAddressModel```. Anyway, I have found the cause and will post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you called `Blueprint.response()` before `Blueprint.get()`. So do like this.

```
@address_blueprint.get('/child/address/<string:person_id>/list')
@address_blueprint.response(status_code=200, schema=ChildAddressDetailsSchema)
def get_child_address(person_id):
    ...
```

A Python decorator returns a new function that calls the original function. So the order of decorators matters in general. In this case, the implementation of the `ResponseMixin.response()` of Flask Smorest does not work correctly if the `Blueprint.route()`(which is equivalent to the `Scaffold.get()`) is not called before.

You can see that on [this](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/flask-smorest/blob/0.40.0/flask_smorest/response.py#L25) and [this](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/flask-smorest/blob/0.40.0/flask_smorest/blueprint.py#L153). If the `ResponseMixin.response()` is called before the `Blueprint.route()`, the closure `wrapper`(created at the `decorator()` inside the `ResponseMixin.response()`) will be ignored, because the `add_url_rule()` will be called with the original endpoint function not the `wrapper`, at the `decorator()` inside the `Blueprint.route()`.

Comment: Spot on. Thanks. (flask-smorest maintainer speaking)